# sharepoint invalid date is shown while returning toDateString() in firefox,safari

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, return, invalidation

i have been working on a while in sharepoint,i would like to return a data from blogs and wants to display in my home page.
            i am using** return date.todatestring()** and **return date.tolocalestring()** to fetch the data from the blog. The date format is day,mmm dd,yyyy. It is said that i have to use this format only by the users. so no formats other than this has to be used.
            Its working for me fine in internet explorer and chrome. but i am getting **invalid date** display in the home page for that blog details instead of the date in **safari,firefox**.
            i am having the latest versions for both safari and firefox. 
            I have checked all the language time zone settings,all ie,firefox,chrome,safari having (english en us).i have searched all the sites for help but no luck ending up myself to ask question in sof,which is my last hope.
             Please help.